# How to give wraptext on span enabled row in React Js Ag-Grid

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid-react

I have a table with a condition where if the value of `activity` is "work", then it enable `span` in the `service` column. otherwise its just regular cell.

```
const gridRef = useRef(); // Optional - for accessing Grid's API
  const [rowData, setRowData] = useState(data1); // Set rowData to Array of Objects, one Object per Row

  const [columnDefs, setColumnDefs] = useState([
    {
      headerName: "Activity",
      field: 'activity',
      initialWidth: 100,
      minWidth: 100,
    },
    {
      headerName: "Act Date",
      field: 'act_date',
      initialWidth: 130,
      minWidth: 130,
    },
    {
      headerName: "Service",
      field: 'service',
      initialWidth: 100,
      minWidth: 100,
      wrapText: true,
      autoHeight: true,
      colSpan: (params) => (
         params.data.activity === 'work' ? 3: 1
      )
    },
    {
      headerName: "APBN",
      field: 'apbn',
      initialWidth: 100,
      minWidth: 100,
    },
{
      headerName: "APBD",
      field: 'apbd',
      initialWidth: 100,
      minWidth: 100,
    },
])

const defaultColDef = useMemo((mode) => ({
    sortable: false,
    resizable: true,
    suppressNavigable: true,
    suppressMovable: true,
    gridRef: true,
    editable: false,
    wrapText: true,
    autoHeight: true,
  }));

return(
<Box
className="ag-theme-alpine"
height: '60ch',
width: '100%',
}}>
<AgGridReact
   className='ag-theme-alpine'
   ref={gridRef} // Ref for accessing Grid's API
   rowData={rowData} // Row Data for Rows
   // rowHeight={rowHeight}
   columnDefs={columnDefs} // Column Defs for Columns
   defaultColDef={defaultColDef} // Default Column Properties
   gridOptions={gridOptions}
   animateRows={true}
   onGridReady={true}
   />
   </Box>
)
```

with the just `wrapText: true` it can work but when i add the `colSpan` condition, it just disable the wrap.
i need it so when the value of `activity` column is "work", the value of `service` column will span the entire row back until `APBD`.